# Percent uncertainty confusion

Tags: homework-and-exercises, measurements

[image]

Here is a problem where you have to calculate percent uncertainty for an angle and its sinus function. It calculates the uncertainty for its angle using the well known formula, then calculates uncertainty for sinus by subtracting maximum and minimum mistake uncertainties to get absolute uncertainty and divides it with its measured value. I understood this problem but then the problem beneath confused me:

[image]

In this problem the extreme volumes were subtracted but then divided by 2. Why is it divided by 2 in this problem but wasn't in the previous one? Can someone explain this plese?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a mistake in the calculations for $\Delta$ or a mistake in the re-usage of $\Delta$ for two different meanings.

Consider measuring two values of $Y$ with a maximum $Y_2$ and minimum $Y_1$. When the $\Delta$ is to denote the approximation to the standard uncertainty of the average value $\langle Y \rangle$, then these two formulations apply for

$$\langle Y \rangle = \frac{1}{2} (Y_1 + Y_2)$$

$$ \Delta Y = \frac{1}{2} (Y_2 - Y_1) $$

When the $\Delta$ is instead to represent the spread between the maximum and minimum value, then $\Delta = (Y_2 - Y_1)$ (without the $1/2$ multiplier).

Perhaps the book will provide a better context to determine whether the confusion is simply a mistake in re-using $\Delta$ for two different meanings.